# Javascript file/Jquery not being rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with the way I'm rendering the file because everything else looks pretty solid, please let me know if it's not. nothing is showing up on my bar where it should since I'm using keyup. Not even an error which I think means jquery is not being rendered. 
Here;s my code

javascript file

```
$(function(){

    $('#search').keyup(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/search/",
            data: { 
                'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });

    });

});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

index.html

```
{% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" id="search" name="search" />

      <ul id="search-results">

      </ul>
```

I'm matching id as search but nothing shows up

my javascript file is in my static folder->another static->js>then ajax.js 
so this is how I did `<script src="{% static 'js/ajax.js' %}"></script>`

Not sure if my python code is right, because it's not being rendered at all. 
Here;s my python code

```
def search_titles(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        search_text = request.POST['search_text']
    else:
        search_text = ""

    categories = Category.objects.filter(name__contains=search_text)
    return render_to_response('ajax_search.html',{'categories':categories})
```

ajax search.html is

```
{% if categories.count > 0 %}

{% for category in categories %}
    <li><a href="/category/{{post.category}}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}

{% else %}

<li>None to show!</li>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: I forgot to add my url  url(r'^search/$', 'main.views.search_titles'),

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to use self invoking anonymous function but actually you forgot to call it.

```
$(function(){
    ...
})();
```

Comment: thanks for the try but umm...hmm I'm not good at jquery but I've never heard of adding (); at the end of my function. and I'm invoking function with id named search

Comment: this concept is javascript-specific (I mean, self invoking functions)

Comment: without invoking it the event callbacks you have defined will not be bound, just try it and see if it works

Comment: oh ok, so try putting (); at the end of first function?

Comment: yes, just like I did it in the code snippet inside my answer

Comment: did you try to examine if a request is sent to the server? try to use wdb.server to debug Python code

Comment: no request is not being sent, I don't understand this because I have set ajax.js and index.html right with same id name....

Comment: I'm doing the exact same thing as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKSNciGr8kY but it just wont work in my case....]

Comment: Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: it is hard to say what exactly is wrong here since I don't have the source code of this and there may be lots of things that could go wrong